# How to reduce the size of my custom iOS framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-frameworks, swift-framework

I'd created a custom framework in iOS, with swift4 in Xcode 9.2. The framework contains 9 .swift files, when I tried to archive and create a .framework file, the resultant shows a size of 5MB. However, the 9swift files totally shows a file size of just 72KB. The archived, .framework file is too big in size(5 MB) which my client doesn't agree with.

I'd tried to remove the unwanted code but still the size remains the same, they want me to make it like that of Android framework, which is just 34KB of size. This is the first time I'm creating a framework and I'm out of solutions, can someone help me to reduce the size of the framework without reducing the files?

Comment: I had a look at [Framework Size](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/framework-size/) and [Understanding iOS framework size](https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-framework-size/) and I just wonder if your just have multiple binaries included in the framework - from what I understand, you shouldn't need to remove them or otherwise do anything as Apple does it at their end - but I could wrong

Comment: Yes, I have the bundled .framework file, which will work with simulator and with real device, hope you're referring to that by the term binaries, please correct me if I'm wrong, also do suggest your answer to help me reduce the size?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to it in terms of the binaries. Personally, I think your client needs to not worry about it, there's a significant difference in the way that the binaries for iOS and Android work in - but that's just my opinion

Comment: I should know clearly if there's no way to reduce the size, before informing them of it, that's why I'm trying to find if there's something that I'd missed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I've tried and it has worked for me. Maybe it can also be useful for you.

The linker exports all the symbols by default. You can limit that through some techniques discussed [in this article about Symbol Visibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001670-97603). Also, there is a nice feature in the linker that allows you specify with symbols must be exported or not exported. [Exporting only the interface symbols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/ExportingInterfaces.html) might help you reduce size and your client not waste memory.

So, in practice:

1. Considering that my framework archive is `MyFramework.framework`.
2. I've listed all symbols of `MyFramework.framework/MyFramework` by running `$ nm -g MyFramework.framework/MyFramework` and selected the symbols that my binary needed to export (symbols my client would need to access).
3. All selected symbols were saved in a text file. So assuming that among all the symbols listed, you'll need to save to the text file only the ones you need (your client needs).
4. Open `MyFramework` project and set `Build Settings -> Exported Symbols File` to point to the text file you just created.
5. With the binary in hands, you can strip some symbols using `strip -N MyFramework.framework/MyFramework`.

In my case I could achieve something good but I think it might change from project to project. Also, I was dealing with Objective-C. I made a sample Swift project with the results achieved. You can check it out at https://github.com/gbazilio/ios-framework-size.

Hope it helps for you as it did for me.

Comment: Can you explain me the process in steps how did you achieve it . from the beginning of creating universal target .

Comment: (1) You get you original `.framework` as step number 1 states. (2) You run `nm -g ABC.framework/ABCBinary` to get all the exported symbols. (3) You remove the symbols that are not needed. You should select only the ones that your client will be interfacing with. (4) You save that in a text file and set its path in `Build Settings -> Exported Symbols File`. (5) You rebuild your .framework. And then you can run `nm -g ABC.framework/ABCBinary` again to check if the exported symbols has changed accordingly. (6) Then you do the strip step mentioned in the original answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate step 1 & 2  bit further?